# Can I use Apache Nifi as a ESB or a request mediator?

Tags: apache-nifi, esb

I've seen Apache Nifi compared to similar ETL tools like Apache Flume, Airflow and Kafka. These are ETL tools more than ESBs or request mediators.

ESBs/request mediators can be used to orchestrate web services and expose a single service (a proxy service) which is expected to serve concurrent HTTP requests efficiently.

My question is, can I use Apache Nifi for the same purpose? To provide service orchestration and serve proxy service endpoints using Nifi's processors such as HandleHttpRequest? Is it designed to handle real-time concurrent requests efficiently?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You brought up a few technologies that are quite different..

Apache NiFi is a dataflow management tool. Unlike, Kafka Streams, Airflow or Apache Flume, it does not require you to write your own code. You can do almost anything you need using the existing processors developed by Apache.

Besides, Airflow is a workflow management tool, could be compared with Oozie.

NiFi is made for real time performance but not for serving as a Rest API. It can start a flow based on an http request like you said though.

Hope it helps